# multiple links, linking to the same place

Tags: html, url, linker

Is there a technique to link to the same place for multiple buttons without having to write it out twice?

Usually this wouldn't bother me much but for my portfolio site I have a link to a larger version of a picture on two places: a button and a text. When you scroll through the pictures like a gallery a photo shows up twice because I've linked it two times. What would be the best way to solve this?

LINK TO MY SITE: http://michaeltruong.ca
(click on a button that says "Enlarge" and scroll through the pictures to see what I mean)

Thanks!

Comment: why did you link it two times?

Comment: one for the button and one for the text link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I see that both the 'Text' link and the 'Enlarge' link are pointing to the same class 'group3' as shown below:

```
<a class="group3" href="images/logoredesigns-large.png" title="Logo Redesigns">Enlarge</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="group3" href="images/logoredesigns-large.png" title="Logo Redesigns"><h2>Logo Redesigns</h2></a>
```

Therefore you see the pictures appear twice.
An easy solution to this problem is to have two different grouping classes (say group2 for Text links and group 3 for Enlarge links) as shown below

```
<a class="group2" href="images/logoredesigns-large.png" title="Logo Redesigns">Enlarge</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="group3" href="images/logoredesigns-large.png" title="Logo Redesigns"><h2>Logo Redesigns</h2></a>
```

Then in your javascript code set colorbox for both the groups as shown below

```
$(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', height:"100%"});
$(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', height:"100%"});
```

Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if it works for you.